# WSL doesn't update when Windows file system is updated

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here is my issue:

- I edit a file on Windows, using a Windows file editor.
- I save it to my Documents folder.
- I try to compile the file on WSL using gcc.
- If I saved the file as a new file, I can find it and work with it.
- If I save the file without creating a new file (just using Ctrl+S), WSL doesn't notice the changes. `cat file.c` shows the old file, and there is no way to update it.

Is there any way to make WSL recognise that the file has been updated, and show the new version?

Comment: I'm trying, but this question does not seem very clear to me.  Are you saying that if you edit a file using a Windows program, and then try to look at that file with a WSL program, that the WSL program sees an older version of that same file?

Comment: Yes exactly - I've updated the question so it's hopefully more clear.

Comment: Because this sounds like something Windows is doing wrong, I have to ask, have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: Yes absolutely - restarting both WSL and Windows.   Doesn't seem to help, though even if it did this would be really inconvenient and I'd be surprised if it was expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the edits - it is much clearer now.  Is the Windows file editor closed at the point that you try to access the file with WSL?  Could there be some odd delayed write behaviour?

Comment: The editor is gedit. I don't think it is, but I'll try closing the editor next time I'm on the computer to see if that has something to do with it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Windows 10 Creators Update or later, WSL does support File Change Notifications via iNotify, so if you open & edit a file in gedit, VSCode, Sublime, Notepad, Notepad++, etc. and hit save, the file will be updated and WSL should receive the inotify file change notification.

> Note: If you repeatedly hit CTRL+S in some editors, they won't write to the file until the editor's contents have changed. Try inserting and deleting a space (to fool the editor into thinking its contents have changed) and re-saving afterwards.

Alternatively, try another editor (e.g. one listed above).